# Prove that $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx >0$

Tags: integration, analysis, proof-verification

I was wondering if you guys could verify my proof for the following claim.  I'm told by a colleague that it's incorrect, but I can't figure out why.

If $f$ is continuous and nonnegative on $[a,b]$, and if there is a point $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)>0$ (strictly), prove that $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx >0$.

pf.  $f$ is continuous so $f\geq 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.  Suppose there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)>0$.  Since $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is integrable.  Thus for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ where $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$.  Furthermore, since $f\geq 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x)>0$, then $U(f,P)>0$.  Since $U-L<\epsilon$, then $L>0$.  So we have that

$$0<L(f,P)\leq (L)\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\leq \int_a^b f(x)\,dx=(u)\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\leq U(f,P).$$  So then $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx >0$.

Comment: This does not work since this does not use the continuity of $f$ except to deduce that $f$ is integrable and since the result does not hold for integrable functions.

Comment: Isn't this a small consequence of Chebyhev's inequality… (must assume measurability, which it is)?

Answer (score 1):

The correct argument would be :

As f is continous at $c \in ]a,b[$, there exist $\delta > 0$ such that  $ \forall x\in [c-\delta,c+\delta] \subset [a,b]$, $\frac{f(c)}{2}< f(x) < \frac{3f(c)}{2}$. So you have

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^{c-\delta} f(x)dx + \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} f(x)dx +\int_{c+\delta}^b f(x)dx \geq \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} f(x)dx $$

and

$$\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} f(x)dx  \geq \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} \frac{f(c)}{2}dx = \delta f(c) > 0$$

Comment: I gotta review my measure and integration theory. Better get out my old copies of Kestelman and Taylor............